# Laravel 5.6 resource implicit binding doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

in my router:

```
Route::resource('test', 'TestController');
```

in my controller:

```
public function show(Test $test)
{
    print_r($test);
}
```

I've assumed from the docs that the resource route implicitly gets the model instance from the url like: "test/show/1" - and finds it in the database, but I get a 404 error, is there something else I've missed to make this work?

laravel version 5.6(last for now)

Comment: try `GET /test/1` instead

Comment: @Derek saved my day

Comment: Glad I could help! I can write out an answer if you'd like